proactive messaging to a meeting chat without manual installtion of the bot
I have a bot which sends notifications to a specific Teams meeting, based on the following sample: meeting notifications bot.
In order to get this bot to successfully send messages to a meeting chat, I have to manually install it for the specific meeting (i.e. to add the app manually from within the meeting).
This bot requires the RSC permission OnlineMeetingNotification.Send.Chat, and the consent is probably given during this manual installation.
My requirement:
I'd like to avoid having the user manually install the app - I'd like to either:

install it on the fly (by another 'recording bot' which is already present on the meeting due to a recording policy which adds it automatically), or:
having it installed in all meetings in advance, automatically, across the tenant (even ad-hoc meetings).

My issue:
I cannot get the consent for this permission when I add the bot dynamically via graph API (POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chatId}/installedApps from the 'recording bot' which is already on the meeting). I manage to add the bot via Graph API only if I remove the permission requirement from its manifest, but then it can't write to the chat.
If I don't remove this permission from the manifest, I fail to add the bot via Graph API ('ResourceSpecificPermissionsMismatch' error).
I tried to give a pre-consent for this permission via Azure Portal but it's not listed there. I also tried to replace this RSC permission with broader permissions which are listed on Azure Portal, like:
Chat.ReadWrite.All and OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All,
But when the bot tries to write to the chat, I get the exception:
{
"code":"NotEnoughPermissions",
"message":"Bot not allowed to send meeting notification"
}

I also tried to create a custom setup policy to pre-install this app, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

Is there a way to achieve my requirement - i.e. to add the bot on demand to an existing meeting programmatically and give it the permissions to write to the chat? Or have it installed in advance, automatically?
Thank you!

I found a solution:
While adding a bot to the chat, you can automatically consent its permissions (including RSC permissions). It's actually well documented but I somehow missed that. Here's a segment of my code (C#) which achieves that:
var chatId = this.Call.Resource.ChatInfo?.ThreadId;
var appId = "xxxxxxxx"

// Endpoint to install the app to the chat
var endpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chatId}/installedApps";


try
{
    // Serialize the payload to JSON                    
    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "teamsApp@odata.bind", $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{appId}" },
        {
            "consentedPermissionSet", new
            {
                resourceSpecificPermissions = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        permissionValue = "OnlineMeetingNotification.Send.Chat",
                        permissionType = "Application"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

